# I'm confused with the use of the participle phrase

Tags: prepositional-phrases, participles, gerund-clauses

> The first REM period may begin only a half hour **after falling asleep**.

In the sentence, I'm confused with the use of the phrase **after falling asleep**.
Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Rapid Eye Movement** is a process the brain uses to associate events of the day into memory and reassociate long and short-term memory.

When one **falls asleep** one loses some consciousness of the outside world, **eyes are closed**, **breathing becomes less rapid**, and one immediately dives into a **deep sleep** which to an observer is similar to **being unconscious**

It is during this **deep sleep** that **REM** can occur and is observable by **noticing rapid twitches** in the sleeper's eyes.

**Falling asleep** is an idiom used to describe the act of **becoming non-wakeful**.
**After** is the preposition to describe **after which time** *something* will occur.
**After falling asleep** does not designate a **duration of time**, only the **beginning** of a time interval.

> **After falling asleep**, he had a bad dream.
>   **After falling asleep**, he woke up again.

Answer (score 0):

SUPPLEMENTAL to Peter's Answer (not for upvoting):

There is no participle phrase here. The *-ing* verbform *falling* is not employed as a ***participle***, which is a verbform acting as an **adjective**, but as a ***gerund***, which is the *-ing* verbform acting as a **noun**.

```
 PARTICIPLE: The running man ...  
             The man running down the street ...   
     GERUND: Running can make you healthier.  
             I am too old to enjoy running.
```

In your sentence, *falling asleep* is a gerund clause.

- Internally *falling* is a non-finite verb, meaning that it has no tense or specific time reference. It takes the complement *asleep*, and its subject is omitted because what is meant is any situation where anybody falls asleep. *Asleep* is a predicative complement, an adjective designating a state or condition employed here as the figurative destination or final location which verbs of motion like *fall* ordinarily take (etymologically, in fact, *asleep* is a preposition phrase, *on sleep*).
- Externally *falling asleep* is a nominal (noun-like) phrase acting as the object of the preposition *after*. In that context it designates a particular point in time, the moment when somebody falls asleep.

Comment: but what is **asleep**?

Comment: @TRomano Addressed.